# Am I overspawning IO bound web scraping threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, cpu

**TL;DR:**
If I spawn 10 web requests, each on its own thread, with a CPU that has a 4 thread limit, is this okay or inefficient? Threads are IO bound so sit idle while awaiting server response (I believe). How does CPU deal if more than 4 threads return simultaneously?

I've got a script that currently starts a new thread for every file I need to download (each located at a unique URL) through an `http.client.HTTPSConnection`. At max, I may need to spawn 730 threads. I have done this, since the threads are all IO bound work (downloading and saving to file), but I am not sure if they are executing in parallel or if the CPU is only executing a set at a time. Total run time for file sizes ranging between 20MB to 110MB was roughly 15 minutes.

My CPU is quad-core with no Hyper-Threading. This means that it should only support 4 threads simultaneously at any given time. Since the work is IO bound and not CPU bound, am I still limited by the hold of only 4 simultaneous threads?

I suppose what is confusing is I am not sure what sequence of events takes place if say I send out just 1 request on 10 threads; what happens if they all return at the same time? Or how does the CPU choose which 4 to finish before moving onto the next available thread?

And after all of this, if the CPU is only handling 4 threads at a time, I would image it is still smart to spawn as many IO threads as I need (since they will sit idle while waiting for server response) right?

Comment: If you are using 3.4+, consider looking into using asyncio tasks or one of the 3rd-party packages doing something similar.  Task switching should have less overhead than thread  switching.  Note that you cannot literally get responses 'at the same time' as your ethernet port is a serial line transmitting one packet at a time.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Good to know! i will have to look into it. However I'm merely trying to gain a better understanding of process/thread sequencing and use of/impact to CPU architecture. So when I start 100threads (for some odd reason!) and the data returns from the server to each thread, it returns 1 at a time and the CPU is just doing the work remaining in the thread (with a maximum of 4 threads at a time)? If you have a link to an overview of how a CPU manages/handles threads than that is ideal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have significantly more than 4 IO-bound threads on a quad-core CPU.  However, you  do want to have some maximum.  Even IO bound processes use the CPU some of the time.  For example, when a packet is received, that packet needs to be handled to update TCP state.  If you are reading from a socket and writing to a file, some CPU is required to actually copy the characters from the socket buffer to the file buffer under most circumstances.  If you use TLS, CPU is typically required to decrypt and encrypt data.  So even threads that are mostly doing IO use the CPU some.  Eventually the small fraction of time that you are using the CPU will add up and consume the available CPU resources.
Also, note that in Python, because of the global interpreter lock, you can only have one thread using the CPU to run python code at a time.  So, the GIL would not typically be held while doing something like waiting for an outgoing connection.  During that time other threads could be run.  However, for some fraction of the time while reading and writing from a socket or file, the GIL will be held.  It's likely with most common work loads that the performance of your application will reach a maximum when  the fraction of time your threads need a CPU reaches one full CPU rather than four full CPUs.
You may find that using `asyncio` or some other event-driven architecture provides better performance.  When true this is typically because the event-driven model is better at reducing cross-thread contention for resources.
In response to your question edit, I would not expect 10 threads to be a problem

Comment: I did read about the GIL. What exactly does 'run python code [one] at a time` mean? The whole program is Python! When I send `conn.request()` I know that no code is running as that thread is awaiting server response. When it is returned, the thread moves on to the next line of code (which is a `with open()` to write returned data to file). Isnt receiving and writing data to a file still considered IO bound and thus not subject to the GIL? Only my main thread (which is executing a `queue` for status on threads) is constantly in a `while` after all threads are spawned.

Comment: While waiting for a connection, the thread can free the GIL, and let other threads run.  However, when the connection is made, the GIL probably ends up getting grabbed briefly to go update the python objects.  My point is that things cap out closer to 1 CPU's worth of work than 4 CPU's worth.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on "may add up" and "cap out closer to 1 CPUs worth of work"?

Comment: I've edited the answer to try and address your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the update. One last thing, when you state "one full CPU rather than four full CPUs" I only have 1 CPU with 4 cores; did you mean 1 full core? How would they add up if the GIL is only letting 1 run at a time even though GIL is held very briefly.

Comment: By CPU, I mean CPU or core.  If a thread is waiting to get the GIL, then the performance of your application suffers.  So, by the time you've gotten to the point where CPU tasks consume one core, you've likely gotten to the point where adding more threads does not improve performance.

Comment: Well thats what would confuse me: each task does not take enough to lock up an entire core and each core can only run 1 thread at a time. So putting each task on its own thread seems logical, to at least go get the data and wait for the writing portion.

Comment: Sure, but consider.  You have 1000 tasks, and decide to split into 1000 threads.  Each thread takes up 10% of a CPU; that is mostly IO bound, but with a bit left over.  You'll end up being no faster than if you had split the tasks across 10 threads.

Comment: You might end up being much slower with 1000 tasks and 1000 threads because of context switching overhead.  but that would be far beyond one question's worth of answer:-)

Comment: Is there a pythonic way to measure the CPU usage of a thread to find that "sweet spot"? How would I know when a full vote is being used? Is there a general practice for this? I've heard for larger volumes like this, a threadpool may be more ideal. Thoughts?